# Show multiple image at one page taken from Camera with Ionic Native in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, ionic2

I am trying to show images one after another at the same page taken from camera in ionic 2 but I am only able to show one images on the page.
Here is my code:

```
public base64Image: string;
public CompleteImage: Array<{image:string}>;

public OpenCamera() {

    Camera.getPicture({
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 200,
        targetHeight: 200,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    }).then(imageData => {
        alert(1);
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        alert(2);
        this.CompleteImage.push(this.base64Image);
        alert(this.CompleteImage.length);

    }, error => {
        console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

for front end 
if I am using this code

```
<ion-card *ngIf="base64Image">
  <img [src]="base64Image" />     
</ion-card>
```

then it is showing image but from collection. If I am trying to show it

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let i of CompleteImage">              
    <img [src]="i.image"/>
  </ion-card>
```

then it is not working.

Here is the link from where I'm trying to achieve this. [here](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-using-the-camera-with-ionic-native/)

Answer (score 0):

You should Ideally be using the `ImagePicker` API which can be obtained by importing `ImagePicker` from 'ionic-native' library.

```
import { Camera, ImagePicker } from 'ionic-native';
```

Have a function like this in a helper class (if you prefer)

```
export function pickImages() {
    const options = {
        quality: 50,
        width: 1366,
        height: 768,
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
    };
    return ImagePicker.getPictures(options);
}
```

The above function will return a promise. You can use it like this.

```
pickImages().then((results) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
  }
}, (err) => { });
```

Keep in mind this will return the location strings of images. You'll have to read this some other way

Reference
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/image-picker/

Comment: What would happen? Does the app crash?